# Error Could not install package 'Microsoft.Build.Framework 14.3.0'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have used visual studio 2019, I have added some NuGet packages but it's show error like..

```
Error       Could not install package 'Microsoft.Build.Framework 14.3.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Note: My Xamarin Binding library(Android) solution target version9.0.
please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: That package is not compatible with whatever minimum target you have set for your android project

Comment: @Digitalsa 1nt Then how could I resolve that issue, actually I have install Xamarin.Build.AsyncTask - NuGet Package I got this issue.

Comment: Right click on your android project and select properties, then look for 'minimum build target' or something to that effect, and lower it to an older android OS.

Answer (score 0):

Try by updating your Microsoft.Build.Framework package to the latest version (at the moment it is 16.0.461).
You can check it also here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build.Framework/

Answer (score 0):

Once I copied the build task property section from my iOS csproj to my Android csproj.. I got a slightly different message. It asked me to add `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core`.

I then had to add the `Microsoft.Win32.Registry 5` nuget then as it tried to install 4.3.0 which my Android project didn't like.